# How can add image in wordpress custom post?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

How can add image in wordpress custom post? please any one help me....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean a post featured image?
In the functions file for your theme you need to turn support on for the post types you have

You may already have a line that looks like this, just as your postype in the array.
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array('post', 'page', 'CUSTOM_POST_TYPE_HERE'));

Comment: yes i want to add post featured image in wordpress admin panel? and i want to display this images in front panel. Help me.

Comment: finally i have found solution for my answer.

simply refer the following link :

http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/attaching-files-to-your-posts-using-wordpress-custom-meta-boxes-part-1/